# Android Emulator crashing on start - Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, flutter, emulation

I installed the latest version Android Emulator, HAXM, running on Intel i7 930. Tried booting it from CMD, got same results.
It boots up for a second with black screen and shuts down with the messages

```
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\11384 for reading.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\9092 for reading.
```

I disabled this setting, if enabled it doesn't boot up at all:

```
Settings > Tools > Emulator > Launch in a tool window
```

Here's the log:

```
2023-04-05 17:00:41,063 [ 237906]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_2_API_30
2023-04-05 17:00:41,107 [ 237950]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
2023-04-05 17:00:41,107 [ 237950]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Found systemPath C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
2023-04-05 17:00:41,171 [ 238014]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
2023-04-05 17:00:41,268 [ 238111]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
2023-04-05 17:00:41,271 [ 238114]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
2023-04-05 17:00:41,810 [ 238653]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\EVILBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
2023-04-05 17:00:41,810 [ 238653]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2023-04-05 17:00:41,811 [ 238654]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.100.1
2023-04-05 17:00:41,811 [ 238654]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2023-04-05 17:00:41,811 [ 238654]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,033 [ 238876]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected
2023-04-05 17:00:42,178 [ 239021]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
2023-04-05 17:00:42,179 [ 239022]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
2023-04-05 17:00:42,179 [ 239022]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\11384 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,179 [ 239022]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Advertising in: C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_13828.ini
2023-04-05 17:00:42,179 [ 239022]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\9092 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,180 [ 239023]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\11384 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,181 [ 239024]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\9092 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,181 [ 239024]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\11384 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,181 [ 239024]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\9092 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:42,249 [ 239092]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x1920, dpi: 420x420
2023-04-05 17:00:42,464 [ 239307]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - VCPU shutdown request
2023-04-05 17:00:42,464 [ 239307]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execu
2023-04-05 17:00:42,465 [ 239308]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - te vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,465 [ 239308]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,466 [ 239309]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,466 [ 239309]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - T
2023-04-05 17:00:42,466 [ 239309]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - rying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,466 [ 239309]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Deleting snapshot default_boot
2023-04-05 17:00:42,466 [ 239309]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,467 [ 239310]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - 
2023-04-05 17:00:42,467 [ 239310]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,467 [ 239310]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:42,467 [ 239310]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Trying to execute vcpu at eip:000000000009e019
2023-04-05 17:00:43,485 [ 240328]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\11384 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:43,486 [ 240329]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\evilbabaroga\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\9092 for reading.
2023-04-05 17:00:43,636 [ 240479]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Process finished with exit code 0
2023-04-05 17:00:43,871 [ 240714]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.p.ProcessNameMonitor - Removing emulator-5554: 287822543
2023-04-05 17:00:43,871 [ 240714]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
2023-04-05 17:00:47,278 [ 244121]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.DeviceManagerAndroidDebugBridge - []
2023-04-05 17:00:47,311 [ 244154]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.PairedDevicesPanel - No pairs
```

I tried loading the emulator, didn't work out.